# calling a function with same name and same parameters

Tags: python, function

I have two functions a() in a.py and a() in b.py.How do i call the function of a.py a() in b.py. Since both the functions will have same name in b.py i am not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: `from a from a as new_a`. I think you should always try not use such naming convention which will conflict.

Comment: better yet - `import a` and `a.a(....)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can import your module and access its methods so there are no naming collisions:

```
# b.py

import a

a.a()
```

Comment: @iced What is it then?

Comment: it's module. which is not the same as namespace (though very close).

Comment: The module gets imported into different namespace.

Answer (score 1):

First approach is:

```
import a
import b


a.a()
b.a()
```

Another is:

```
from a import a as a_a
from b import a as b_a


a_a()
b_a()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tips: In a general point of view avoid using:

```
from module import *   # IS BAD !
```

it is a huge source of missunderstanding.
If you do it to save the size and readability of you code 
prefer :

```
import module.which.may.be.super.long as M
M.a()
```

you save the trace-ability of your code, keeping Python as an explicit language.